# Insert html in a php script

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I want to use html code to appear in $message when it is sent, thank you.

Here it's the php script

```
<?php
// read the list of emails from the file.
$email_list = file("elist.txt");

// count how many emails there are.
$total_emails = count($email_list);

// go through the list and trim off the newline character.
for ($counter=0; $counter<$total_emails; $counter++) {
    $email_list[$counter] = trim($email_list[$counter]);
}

// implode the list into a single variable, put commas in, apply as $to value.
$to = implode(",",$email_list);

$subject = "TEST";
$message = "TEST";
$headers = 'From: TEST <TEST@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";

if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
    echo "The email has been sent!";
} else {
   echo "The email has failed!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Then write it into $message ??
$message ="YOUR HTML CODE";

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php Look at example 4

Answer (score 1):

Add your html into `$message` and add Content-type.

```
$subject = "TEST";
$message = "<html><body><p>Text</p></body></html>";

$headers = 'From: TEST <TEST@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Read [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22997176/revisions) concerning my edit. In not doing so, would've caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to read:

```
$html = <<<MSG
<html>
 <head>
  ....
 </head>
 <body>
   <h2> text title </h2>
   <span>$variable</span>
   ....
 </body>
</html>

MSG;
```

Be careful not to leave blank spaces after `<<<MSG` or before `MSG;`